# google chrome like close button behavior in css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button

How would you replicate the behavior of tabs in google chrome with css?

one problem I'm having is with the close button (x)

cursory google searches say you shouldn't have a button inside an anchor, but if that's the case I don't know how to replicate the behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you need two separate answers to your question:

- How do you nest the element properly?
- How do you perform the close action?

Let's start with **nesting the elements**. I chose to make my tabs in a `ul` and make each tab an `li` within that list. The close button is an `a` tag that is floated to the right *inside* the `li`.

```
<ul>
    <li>Tab 1 <a>x</a></li>
    <li>Tab 2 <a>x</a></li>
    <li>Tab 3 <a>x</a></li>
    <li>Tab 4 <a>x</a></li>
    <li>Tab 5 <a>x</a></li>
</ul>
```

(I highly recommend you give them all the appropriate classes for what you're trying to do, but for this case, I used the minimal amount of code to keep it clean and easy to read.)

Next up, we'll go into **performing the close action** with JavaScript.

I was able to create the following jsFiddle for you to demonstrate both of these points:

[original jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exHza/4/)

**EDIT:** [revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exHza/6/)

Essentially, the code works as follows:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').animate({padding:0, margin:0, width: 0}, function () {  
        $(this).closest('li').hide();   
    });
});
```

When you click the `a` tag, which is what I've made the x button (similar to a chrome tab), it animates the list item (list of tabs, floated to the left) by changing the padding, margin, and width to 0.

Technically, since I set the li to border-box for the box-sizing, I don't have to have padding:0 in the animate function at all.

When animation is complete, I hide the list item entirely. (I could even remove it entirely at that point if I wanted to get rid of it, but I wanted you to see what I'm doing.)

Some additional takeaways:

- You can have a click event on almost any item in jQuery, but certain mobile devices get finicky if they aren't `a` tags.
- You're correct that you shouldn't put a button inside of an anchor tag, but putting two anchor tags or a button and an anchor tag into one list item is fine.

Everything else like setting the active tab and using a % as a max-width should be pretty obvious, but if you need more help or clarification, just let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I'll try this and see where it goes.

Comment: the problem is then, if you have some kind of indicator for active tab, closing it makes it momentarily active. see: http://jsfiddle.net/exHza/5/

Comment: @HaykSaakian There's no problem, you just use `event.stopPropagation();` on the `a` element click event so it doesn't send the event to any parent nodes in the DOM. See [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exHza/6/)

Comment: @HaykSaakian Anything I can do to help! Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with no javascript code, only using css. Don't know if is the best solution but is certainly fun to know this kind of stuff exists.

Here is the [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJMfd/6/)

HTML: (you should use `<li>` i guess is best for organising)

```
<div class="background" id="background">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
    <div class="text">Tab name 
        <div class="close-button">
            <a href="#background" >x</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS magic :

> @import
>   url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
>
> #background{ 
>       background-color:#d8d8d7;
>       height:30px;  opacity:1;
>       display:table-cell;
>       vertical-align:middle;
>        transition: opacity .5s;
>       -moz-transition: opacity .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
>       -webkit-transition: opacity .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
>       -o-transition: opacity .5s; /* Opera */ 
>       }
>
> #background:target{  opacity:0; }
>
> .text{    display:inline-block; }
>
> .close-button{
>       text-align:center;
>       width:20px;
>       height:20px;  display:inline-block;
>       -webkit-border-radius: 50%;   -moz-border-radius: 50%;    border-radius: 50%; }
>
> .close-button:hover{  background-color:#ec8e92; }
>
> .close-button:active{     background-color:#cc7d80; }
>
> .close-button a{  text-decoration:none;
>       color:#868687; }
>
> .close-button a:hover{    color:#FFFFFF; }

Hope it helps, or at least opens your CSS horizons.

Cheers.

Comment: nice, i didnt realize you could get so fancy with CSS

Comment: Some issues with this answer: the vendor prefixed attributes should always come after the default css attribute (prefixes should come first so it falls through properly [see this article](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/)), the hover on the x button is sloppy (hovers only on the x, not on the full background--move the `.close-button a:hover` to `.close-button:hover a` [see this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJMfd/8/)), and from a stylistic standpoint, you're mixing uppercase and lowercase for all your hex codes--but that's just nitpicking.

Comment: @aerodynamo I've realized that, the <a> was actually wrong, but I did the snippet in my coffee break at work, didn't get the chance to finish, but thanks for the prefixed tip!!

Comment: @LucasLazaro Happy to help, and I understand how snippets during coffee breaks go. :)